# Use sequential numbers for entry slug

Tags: url, slug, entry-slug

I have a channel where I need each entry's URI include the year and then a sequential number, like this:
2018/1/
2018/2/
2018/3/
2019/4/

I have no problem getting the year, but is there a way to get the entry slug to be a sequential number?

Comment: Would it be an option to include an "increment" field in the layout that stores this number and increases +1 for each entry? Another option is to create a query and fetch the current position of your element whenever you store it.